# How create this border with css

Tags: html, css

I want put this border in my html code:

[image]

I want the border that you can see in the image so I use my css code:

```
border: 1px outset #999999;
border-top:none;
border-left: none;
```

Bt the result is not the same. Anyone can help to reproduce the same effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `box-shadow`

> box-shadow: [horizontal offset] [vertical offset] [blur radius]
>   [optional spread radius] [color];

Something like this:

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use box-shadow. ex:

```
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.18);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will require you to have a drop shadow, rather than a border.

```
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px -4px #000000;
```

Try using this, it sets the shadow behind the div.
https://jsfiddle.net/eqm4qbLr/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `border-right`

```css
.border {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #999999;
  border-right: 2px solid #999999;
  height: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="border">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should, instead of a shadow unless that's what you want, use `border-right` and `border-bottom` with `rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)` to set its colour and opacity. If you don't want a transparent border you can still put a hex code instead.

```css
.border {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 200px;
 }
 
 p {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<div class=border>
  <p>Sample text</p>
</div>
```